# 'Bad request' error on flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I think my problem is that flask can't find the key and value of my java script. So, how can I fix it?
Here is my python:

```
def ledStudy_handler():
    if request.form['study'] == "on":
            GPIO.output(11, GPIO.HIGH)
            print("lights on")
    elif request.form['study'] == "off":
            GPIO.output(11, GPIO.LOW)
            print("lights off")
    return render_template("home.html")
```

And here is my js:

```
      function ledStudy() {
        var checkStudy = document.getElementById("checkStudy");
        if (checkStudy.checked == true){
          var checkStudy.study = "on";
        } 
        else {
          var checkStudy.study = "off";
        }
      }
```

Comment: How are these being passed? GET/POST?

Comment: Impossible to tell from the provided code, it is missing some important parts such as the code that is responsible for sending data to flask application.

Comment: @LokiSinclair Sorry, I don't get it, I am very new to js and html. What is GET/POST? What do I need to know?